# If a QGIS Attribute Form is too long/high, is it possible to get it to automatically resize or break into 2 columns?

Tags: qgis

I've created a form using the Drag and Drop designer but when there are to many fields to fit in my screen resolution I can't resize it or get scroll bars to see all the fields (2 in image below).

Apart from creating and providing a UI file is there some option that would allow a vertical scroll bar to be seen so I can see all fields? The scroll bar is there when you don't use Drag and Drop designer (1 in image below).

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this directly with the UI Drag & Drop designer (see pictures below):

- Add a container with the plus symbol
- drag all the columns into the container
- double click the container to configure the container and change the number of columns to the desired value

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! Very elegant solution.

Comment: Does this give you a fixed number of columns, or does switch when you change the size of the window?

Comment: I think it's fixed, but I didn't tested it.

Answer (score 2):

alternatively, you can choose to add TABS and split your Fields as various Tab Categories:

[image: TABS]

and your Input Form(s) would then look like this:

[image]

[image]